# power(1.0003,975)=1.339713967

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

`power(1.0003,975)=1.339713967`

but when is executing it than i find `1.3397` as a result but in excel i find accurate result `1.339713967` how to find accurate result in `sql server-2008`

Comment: What is the question not able to get you

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is rather particular about the scale and precision of results with numeric values.

You can get the results you want by being explicit about the types going in.  For instance:

```
select power(cast(1.0003 as decimal(38, 12)), 975)
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/WEJI18183).

Comment: i use this but i got 1.33970000 but i want 1.339713967

Comment: @nakul . . . I actually tested this -- admittedly on a more recent version of SQL Server.  However, I doubt that the treatment of decimals would have changed in the newer releases.